# Программа работает нелогично

Tags: python

```
n = [4]
g = [0, 0, 2, 2]
n1 = int(n[0] / 2)
fin = []
for z in range(n[0]):
    if sum(g[0:n1]) == sum(g[n1:]):
        fin.append(g)
    g.insert(0, g[-1])
    g.pop(-1)
print(fin)
```

Программа должна выводить:

```
[[2, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 2, 0]]
```

А она выводит:

```
[[0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, программа работает логично, поскольку вы добавляете в `fin` **ссылку на список** `g`, а **не его содержимое**:

```
fin.append(g) # добавляется ссылка
```

Поэтому все последующие изменения в `g` тут же отражаются и внутри `fin`. Делайте копию текущего состояния `g` при добавлении в `fin`:

```
fin.append(g.copy()) # добавляется копия содержимого
```

Но и этот метод не универсален, `.copy` копирует только верхний уровень, а если там тоже списки, то будут те же проблемы и нужно уже использовать `copy.deepcopy`, чтобы скопировать вообще всё.

Comment: спасибо большоє)